# Anyone able to help move a C# framework 4.5 class library to a compatible framework with XNA 4.0?

Tags: c#, oop, xna

I've been working with a class library built against `.net 4.5`, and in the middle of development had to move the view of the project to XNA.  I'm running into compatibility errors between the view and model.  Does anyone know how to change the version of `.net` for an already existing project?  Creating a new project seems less ideal than flipping a switch somewhere in the options.

Comment: XNA no longer is being developed.  Are you sure you want to develope against the .NET Framework 4.0 and XNA which won't be updated nor any new features ever be added in the future?

Comment: IF the project carries out much longer I could always make a few slight changes to it for the MonoGame version of XNA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem, by merely switching the framework to .NET 4.0, in the properties pane.  I don't believe I was using anything specific to 4.5.